# Не понимаю как взаимодействовать с графической сценой и элементами на ней Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Есть шахматная доска, и фигурки на ней, фигурки вида QGraphicsPixmapItem, я не могу понять как мне взаимодействоать с этим игровым полем, как например сделать так чтобы при нажатии на фигуру я смог например переставить ее, как связать это действие и эту картинку, сами фигуры находятся в контейнере QVector. Ниже будет код, и как пример пара фигур на нем. Так же буду очень благодарен за какой нибудь пример.

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene();
view = new QGraphicsView();

this->setScene(scene);

scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 800, 800);

bool isWhite = true;
for (int y = 0; y < 800; y += 100) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 800; x += 100 ) {
        QBrush brush;
        if(isWhite) brush = QBrush(Qt::white);
        else brush = QBrush(Qt::gray);
        scene->addRect(x,y,100,100,QPen(Qt::black), brush);

        if(isWhite) isWhite = false;
        else isWhite = true;
    }

    if(isWhite) isWhite = false;
    else isWhite = true;
}

int posX = 0;
int posY = 0;

QGraphicsPixmapItem *figure = 0;

figure = scene->addPixmap(QPixmap("blackFigure.png").scaled(100, 100,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
figure->setPos(posX, posY);
blackFigures.append(figure);

posX += 200;
figure = scene->addPixmap(QPixmap("blackFigure.png").scaled(100, 100,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
figure->setPos(posX, posY);
blackFigures.append(figure);

posX += 200;
figure = scene->addPixmap(QPixmap("blackFigure.png").scaled(100, 100,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
figure->setPos(posX, posY);
blackFigures.append(figure);

posX += 200;
figure = scene->addPixmap(QPixmap("blackFigure.png").scaled(100, 100,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
figure->setPos(posX, posY);
blackFigures.append(figure);
```

Comment: Нужно переопределить евенты мыши для вашего класса, который представляет фигуры. Тобишь эвент нажатия левой кнопки мыши, эвент перемещения мыши и эвент отпускания левой кнопки мыши

Comment: Огромное спасибо